# Importing Vue Router inside a JavaScript file causes 'Module Parse Failed' Error

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router, loader

I am trying to access the router in the interceptor of axios, but when I import the file in a `.js` Axios file, an error `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders > <template>` occurs.

Here is a sample of the router.js file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

const router = {
     base: process.env.BASE_URL,
     routes: [
          {
               path: "/settings",
               name: "settings",
               component: require('@/views/Settings.vue'),
          }
     ]
};
export default new Router(router);
```

And the interceptor file contains:

```
import router from './router';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you using `require('@/views/Settings.vue')`?

Instead try to use `import` function.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = {
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/settings',
      name: 'settings',
      component: () => import('@/views/Settings.vue'),
    },
  ],
};
export default new Router(router);
```

PS: Answer your comment.
In `main.js` file export the instance variable:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let vm = new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

export default vm; // ATENTION HERE
```

In `axios.js` file import the `main.js` and access the `$router`:

```js
import vm from './main.js';
...
  // YOUR INTERCEPTOR
  vm.$router.push({ name: 'settings' });
...
```

Comment: I have tried it before, but it resulted in the same problem.

Comment: The code is not mine, but the main idea is that I am creating an instance using axios.create and listening to responses using: instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {...}) in which I have to change the route in some cases.

Comment: Why do you want to change the routes in Axios file?

Comment: I want to redirect the user to the main page if he/she was on some other page and a specific response was sent during that time.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: This did not solve my problem either, so I changed my approach but I think it has to do with the architecture of my application where I have multiple routers. However, I am sure that the solutions you presented work fine in normal cases. Thank you for your help!